Progress bar on xarray.open_mfdataset?
I'm using xarray.open_mfdataset() to open tens of thousands of (fairly small) netCDF files, and it's taking quite some time. Being of an impatient nature, I would like to at least be assured that something is happening, so a progress bar would be nice. I found an example of using a progress bar from dask here: https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/4000#issuecomment-619003228
However, my attempt to adapt this solution doesn't show a progress bar. Any other options?
Here is the code I tried:
import xarray as xr
from dask.diagnostics import ProgressBar

with ProgressBar():
    d = xr.open_mfdataset('proc/*.nc')

Updated:
After discussion with a colleague, we ended up with this solution:
import xarray as xr
from dask.diagnostics import ProgressBar
with xr.open_mfdataset('proc/*.nc', chunks=dict(index=1)) as d, ProgressBar():
    d.load()

This works in the strict sense that it displays a progress bar, but unfortunately it does nothing (no progress bar visible) for a couple of minutes (for the set of files I tested), and then the progress bar shows up and runs through in a few seconds. In other words, not very useful for an impatient soul like me.

Problem is that open_mfdataset first checks all file metadata to construct the DataSet, and then start to really load the data. You should probably try with the parralel kwarg.
